# Angular provider useFactory injection

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a factory provider service, which should choose service depending of the flag. When need a debug students service all working is good, but when I change flag on false the app throw ERROR TypeError: serverService.fetchData is not a function. How fix that?

```
Students.provider
import { StudentDebugService } from "./student-debug.service";
import { StudentService } from "./student.service";
import { ServerService } from "./server.service";

const isNeedDebug: boolean = false;

const studentServiceFactory = (studentDebugService: StudentDebugService, serverService: ServerService) => {
  if (isNeedDebug) {
    return new StudentService(studentDebugService.students);
  }
  serverService.fetchData().subscribe( (students) => {
    return new StudentService(students);
  });
};

export let studentServiceProvider = {
  provide: StudentService,
  useFactory: studentServiceFactory,
  deps: [ServerService, StudentDebugService]
};
```

```
StudentsService
import { Inject, Injectable } from "@angular/core";

export interface StudentsArgs {
  id: number;
  surName: string;
  name: string;
  middleName: string;
  birthday: string;
  averageRate: number;
}

@Injectable({providedIn: "root"})
export class StudentService {
  constructor(@Inject(StudentService)public students: StudentsArgs[]) {
  }
  getStudents(): StudentsArgs[] {
    return this.students;
  }
}
```

```
ServerService
import { HttpClient } from "@angular/common/http";
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { Observable } from "rxjs";


@Injectable({providedIn: "root"})
export class ServerService {
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
  }
  fetchData(): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get("http://localhost:3000/api");
  }
}
```

StudentsProvider should inject a needed service in app.component.constructor

```
App.Component.ts
import {ChangeDetectionStrategy, Component, Inject, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import { StudentsArgs, StudentService } from "./services/student.service";


@Component({
  selector: "app-root",
  templateUrl: "./app.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./app.component.css"],
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  students: StudentsArgs[] = [];

  constructor(private studentService: StudentService) {
  }
  ngOnInit(): void {
    console.log(this.studentService);
    this.students = this.studentService.students;
  }
```

App.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from "@angular/core";
import { BrowserModule } from "@angular/platform-browser";

import { HttpClientModule } from "@angular/common/http";
import { FormsModule } from "@angular/forms";
import { AppComponent } from "./app.component";
import { studentServiceProvider } from "./services/student.service.provider";
import {ServerService} from './services/server.service';
import {StudentDebugService} from './services/student-debug.service';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpClientModule,
  ],
  providers: [studentServiceProvider],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: Just to double check, you're providing the `studentServiceProvider` in a module, right?

Comment: Yeah, only in module

Comment: and what does your `ServerService` looks like? Where/How are you providing it?

Comment: ServerService should take data from server(http.get) and then put them in StudentService.students. Finaly, StudentService.students should be puts in component. I'm added a component code in post

Comment: Can you also add to your question where you're providing the `studentServiceProvider`? As in the module code

Comment: sure. Already added it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok found the issue. The order matters when it comes to dependencies apparently.

Just swap your `deps`: `deps: [ServerService, StudentDebugService]`

Here's the [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-txvtkq?file=src%2Fapp%2Fstudents.provider.ts)

Comment: Thank you, that fix error.
Unfortunately now i have a undefined StudentService problem in app.component